# Docker not running on Ubuntu WSL due to error cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running WSL 2 (Ubuntu) on a Windows 10 machine. I installed Docker on my Ubuntu using the official Docker guide (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository). Running `docker run hello-world` produces the following error: `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`.

I have tried the following steps:

1. Using `sudo docker...` instead of `docker...`
2. Adding user to docker usergroup with  `sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`
3. `sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &` which I found in this thread: https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host/8925/4

None of these steps helped.

`docker version` produces this output:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b7f0
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:25:46 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

`service docker status` gives `Docker is not running`. `service docker start/restart` does nothing, Docker does not start. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Just hit same issue myself... must be something to do with how you've set groups up because I've also followed along with https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9 but elected not to setup groups and hit same issue. Solution was to just run the docker command as root (i.e. sudo the command and voila)

Comment: Running `$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start` as  byte mamba said below solved my problem.

Comment: This did the trick: `sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy`

Comment: This worked for me: **sudo service docker start**

Comment: You can try to start the docker daemon manually : just type "sudo dockerd &" and go in another terminal and type a docker command.

Answer (score 98):

**Using WSL2**

You simply have to activate and use WSL2, I have to install Ubuntu 20.04 as the 18.04 wasn't connecting with Docker desktop. In the windows shell:

*To check the WSL mode, run*

`wsl -l -v`

*To upgrade your existing Linux distro to v2, run:*

`wsl --set-version (distro name) 2`

*WSL Integration will be enabled on your default WSL distribution. To change your default WSL distro, run*

`wsl --set-default <distro name>`

Then in docker you have to.

...use the WSL2 engine
[image: Activate WSL2]

...access from your default WSL2
[image]

Based on this article.
[A Linux Dev Environment on Windows with WSL 2, Docker Desktop](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows-with-wsl-2-docker-desktop-and-more)
And the docker docs.
[Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)

**Below is valid only for WSL1**

*It seems that docker cannot run inside WSL. What they propose is to connect the WSL to your docker desktop running in windows: [Setting Up Docker for Windows and WSL](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)*

*In the docker forums they also refer to that solution: [Cannot connect to the docker daemon](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock/80886)*

Comment: Upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 -> 20.04 was all I needed

Comment: I also had to enable the integration with the distro installed (in my case it was Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. @PalBo asked how to use Docker when it's installed through the normal Ubuntu installation process, not when using Docker Desktop installed on the Windows operating system containing the WSL 2 distro.

Comment: For Windows 10 Home it is not possible to install the Docker Desktop (error: "HyperV is not available on Home editions. Please use Docker Toolbox"). Of course, Toolbox is deprecated, no longer available on the site. Instead, followed this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps, yet step #5 may not work because the "Legacy" distro is in use. Instead, followed this post's instructions with the exact PowerShell commands: `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2` and after finishing converting, `wsl --set-default Ubuntu 2`. That was it, WSL2 can run hello-world.

Comment: This command can solve my problem：
`$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start`

Comment: doesn't work for me at least on Win 11

Comment: Could you please replace the images with text? The images do not load in our corporate environment due to proxy policy.

Comment: Similarly to what the comment above mentioned, if you want to actually run docker in ubuntu, running `sudo dockerd` worked for me (it will run the docker daemon so you need to open up another terminal after that, or run it in the background ... Also, I wasn't able to login into a running docker image this way, but the images would run)

Comment: Fixed my issue on win10 with wsl ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: 'docker start' did it. How silly of me not to realize that, lol.

Comment: Thanks alot, this sovled my problem. I am using WSL1 for some reasons and WSL1 and I have installed Docker on Windows (using WSL2). Now I can use Docker (installed on WSL1) on my WSL1.

Comment: Thanks, I executed `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2` and then it worked. Strange that this is the only place online I've found this info despite searching for eons.

Comment: Also, extremely useful advice when running multiple distros on wsl. I used this powershell advice to switch Ubuntu-22.04 to be my default for docker.

Answer (score 11):

Go into `PowerShell` and type: `docker context ls`

Output:

```
NAME                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                  KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *           Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine                         swarm
```

Go back into your wsl/ubuntu setup and type:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

This should automatically show your full output when typing `docker version`.

Comment: Nothing changed after doing this, still getting the same message