# docker: unrecognized service

Tags: docker, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting this error while running

```
>service docker start                                                       
docker: unrecognized service
>service docker.io start                                                    
docker.io: unrecognized service
```

I am struggling with docker in order to run it. I got `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` error. thereafter I tried several things but it did not work.

```
>docker pull pstothard/cgview                                               
Using default tag: latest                                                                                      
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

 >sudo docker run hello-world                                                
 docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

>systemctl start docker.service                                             
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

>docker images                                                             
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: 
Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied 

>snap stop docker                                                           
Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.                                      
This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 app in windows system. what should I do?

Comment: Is this WSL2 and have you followed [the docs for setting it up with docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)?

Comment: I don't  have WSL2. i  have installed  docker using sudo apt-get install docker

Comment: Well is it WSL 1 then? The output `Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.` in your screenshot seems to say you are making use of WSL.

Comment: @octagon_octopus  so what should I do?

Comment: I need you to answer my question in my previous comment. I can't help you if I don't know what you are using. If it's WSL 1 then there are plenty of guides on the internet to help you set it up too in case you haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @octagon_octopus but how to know what is at the backend WSL1 or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218278/discussion-between-octagon-octopus-and-vibhu-sharma).

Answer (score 9):

Seems like WSL cannot connect to the docker daemon running through Docker for Windows, probably because it is not exposed or is not running.

**WSL1**

In case you are using WSL 1, you can expose the docker daemon through this option in Docker for Windows:
[image]
I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592709/docker-not-running-on-ubuntu-wsl-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix) article for a detailed guide.

I would highly recommend running docker within WSL 2 instead, since it provides faster boot times and allows docker to use CPU/RAM dynamically instead of you having to preallocate it.

**WSL2**

In case you are using WSL 2, you will have to enable the WSL 2 back-end for docker through Docker for Windows. The docker team has an extensive guide on this [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/).

Comment: For example in my case I tried to set up docker in wsl2 ubuntu because I didn't want to install Docker for Windows. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: @Geff I've got docker working on WSL2 without Docker for Windows before. Unfortunately it's a little too vague to remember the gotchas, but I don't believe there were many (if at all), so I think you will get pretty far by using the standard Ubuntu install guide from the Docker team. Only issue i remember is that systemd still has problems on WSL 2, so I had to manually `service docker start`.

Answer (score 5):

Try starting the docker deamon manually (`sudo dockerd`) if the `sudo docker run hello-world` returns `Is the docker daemon running?`.

Comment: yes, but then why docker doesn't start when I use service docker start in WSL?

Comment: using command 'sudo dockerd' starts docker in a terminal not in background.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, what I simply did was to set my default Linux distro. Try running `wsl --setdefault <distroName>`. In my case `wsl --setdefault ubuntu`. You should be able to run commands after this.