# Can't get past "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" Error on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2, podman, docker-daemon

I am a Windows user trying to run "docker-compose up" command but continue to get the error in title. I am writing this code in Ubuntu using WSL 2.

I have tried everything - from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker) to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012885/docker-unrecognized-service) - and have made sure I have docker installed correctly. When I run "sudo service docker start" I get "docker: unrecognized service". I'm thinking of switching to Podman (though would prefer not to if can avoid it) to get past having to use the docker daemon- though I can't seem to get this to run in wsl.

Any and all guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that your Docker Service is not running.

Open RUN and type services.msc, then click OK or hit enter

Search for service named as `Docker Desktop Service`.
Make sure it is running.

You can also set the Docker service to start when you login from Docker Desktop GUI setting panel

[image: Docker Desktop Settings]

Comment: I confirmed that my Docker Desktop Service is indeed running, and I have checked that box you pointed to, but I am getting the same error :( Do I need to check any other boxes in the General settings ie "Use Docker Compose V2" or "expose daemon.."? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Wait....? 'sudo' on windows

Comment: Miss read your questions first 3 lines. Run that command in cmd and bot in WSL2. Docker uses it. WSL has knowledge  of existing windows services but lacks the ablity to use them.