# Error initializing Docker client: protocol not available running terraform import command

Tags: docker, terraform

I'm trying to work my way through the [Import Terraform Configuration](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/state-import?in=terraform/state) tutorial on the learn.hashicorp.com site. When I try to run the terraform import command in the tutorial, I get the following error:

```
$ terraform import docker_container.web $(docker inspect --format="{{.ID}}" hashicorp-learn)
╷
│ Error: Error initializing Docker client: protocol not available
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
│   on /Users/ac8dqzz/myrepos/terraform/learn-terraform-import/main.tf line 14, in provider "docker":
│   14: provider "docker" {
│ 
╵
```

Googling this error has not yielded anything of relevance to my particular case. My main.tf file looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "~> 2.16"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.14"
}

provider "docker" {
  host    = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"
}
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem here is?

Answer (score 12):

Replace `host    = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"` with `host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"` its works for me in mac. see the complete solution below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "~> 2.7"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.14"
}

provider "docker" {
  host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
}
```

Comment: it worked also in Windows WSL 2

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the [docker is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592709/docker-not-running-on-ubuntu-wsl-due-to-error-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemo) (use `docker ps`) before `terraform apply`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run two commands `terraform init` and `terraform apply` as root user and then it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace host    = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine" with host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock" it worked for me also on Linux (Rocky9)